# IT job interview and requirements

Tags: software-industry, hiring-process

I have a job interview next week and the job description does not indicate things that I must know. The only listed requirement is a college diploma. Since applying, I have heard through the grapevine that the job entails knowledge of A, B, C and D.

I have working knowledge of A and B and I know that during the interview C and D will come up.  How do I tell/show this employer that even though I have never done C or D in my university education, my background in IT will enable me to easily pick up C and D on the job?

This is a junior position and I will be working under a more senior employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a junior position then there won't be a solid set of requirements as such, bar any main languages they use (i.e. c#/php etc).

The fact is, you have the interview. This means that on paper, you have been deemed to have sufficient skills to do the job. They aren't going to interview people who they know wouldn't be able to do the job.

Now, all you need to do is demonstrate what you know confidently, be honest about what you don't know **yet**. Demonstrate your ability to learn and maybe discuss loosely C and D if you have any knowledge of them (even if not working knowledge).

If you try to blag your way through knowing C and D, you won't get the job, OR you will get the job and be way in over your head. Honesty is the best policy here.

Answer (score 5):

If they didn't state it as a requirement, you may not need it to be hired; they apparently agree that you can learn it on the job. On the other hand, an applicant who already has that skill will have an advantage.

All you can do is apply, convince them you will learn quickly, and see what happens. Or develop the skill first, but by the time you do that this opening may be gone.

Go for it. The worst they can say is no.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i am trying to find out.  How to convince then?

Comment: @JerryK You say that you know A and B, so I guess you want to focus on those. If your last experience was from University, talk about a time when you needed to solve a problem or complete a project using something couldn't do yet, X. Explain briefly how you were able to use your knowledge of A and B to learn X to solve the problem. If you could learn X, why can't you learn C and D as well? Don't say the last part directly.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a junior/ graduate position then they probably expect you not to know every subject they like. This happened to me when i didn't know c# for my current job, but told them i learned a wide variety of languages in university and could pick it up easily.

Also, these kind of jobs often want to see enthusiasm and passion for the industry so it's a good idea to make out that you will really enjoy learning those new technologies and that you have already started researching some of them.

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace. Please focus on the exact question of the author, which is HOW can he show his capacity to adapt. Your current answer says he should show it, but does not answer how.